# How to import ssl module inside python's logging.conf?

Tags: python, ssl, logging

I try to use my custom loggingHandler and want to pass to it ssl context in constructor arguments, but have no idea, how  to import ssl module.
There is part of my logging.conf

```
[handler_remoteHttpKafkaHandlerDebug]
class = xxx_some_service.http_logging.KafkaHTTPHandler
level = DEBUG
args = ('10.31.7.197:9898', '/log', 'SOME.KAFKA-TOPIC-LOGS-DEBUG', 1, True, ('root','god'), ssl.create_default_context(.....), 10, 60)
```

Sure, my logger failed with

`NameError: name 'ssl' is not defined`

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, guys, looks very "special", but it works:

```
args = ('10.31.7.197:9898', '/log', 'SOME.KAFKA-TOPIC-LOGS', 1, True, ('root','god'), __import__('ssl').create_default_context(), 10, 60)
```